# Android service cancel oncreate

Tags: android, service

i created a service in the onCreate i do some house work instantiate do some checks and so on.

Now the problem is when something goes wrong in the oncreate how do i cancel it or stop it or even throw a exception.

i already have a broadcast to tell the thing that started it or onbind it that something went wrong but how do i "Stop" it i tryed stopself but it does nothing.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service that's started with bindService will continue until the Context it's called from is closed (i.e. Activity is finished) or [unbindService(ServiceConnection)](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService%28android.content.ServiceConnection%29) is called.

When something goes wrong in the onCreate of your service, call stopSelf().  Then, in the broadcast receiver back in your activity, call unbindService(ServiceConnection) and the service will be released and will stop.

Comment: hi. yes if you did not specify sticky as i did. the problem with stopself is that it will stop the service at oncreate its not started yet so how can that work....

Comment: @Pintac You can return START_NOT_STICKY from onCreate if something goes wrong.  The service will continue until the service kills itself AND nothing is bound to it.  So long as the service is bound, it cannot be killed except under memory strain.  You need to stop the service and unbind it, the order is not important.

Comment: Hi. you mean on start becuase oncreate does not have a return type.